# Common Table Expression Error

Tags: sql, windows-xp, ado, common-table-expression

I have to use old school ADODB (not ADO.NET) to execute a statement that contains a Common Table Expression.
I am using (have to use) the SQLOLEDB provider.
The DML statement works fine when executing from a Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 client but not from WinXP or Win2K3 server.
I have profiled the routine and found that the old OSes send a slightly different SQL statement.

```
Win7 + 2008 =    exec sp_executesql N'WITH source(Vsl, Cpt, SrcTyp, SrcNum, Opn, JobNum, Qty, Cst, Vry, Reg, Vnt, Sbk) AS ...'

WinXP + Win2K3 = exec sp_executesql N'exec WITH source(Vsl, Cpt, SrcTyp, SrcNum, Opn, JobNum, Qty, Cst, Vry, Reg, Vnt, Sbk) AS ...'
```

Notice the extra 'exec' slipped into the command text.

It appears as if the verions of SQLOLEDB.1 on the old OSs mis-treats the WITH statement and sees it as needing a prepending 'exec'.

Can anyone shed some light on this. Is there an SQLOLEDB driver update that I can apply to the old OSes? or some other workaround.

Comment: Details help -- if the CTE is not recursive, there's no benefit anyways so you can re-write as a derived table/inline view.

Comment: *Cough* STORED PROCEDURE *cough*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(FYI, You should really revisit some of your existing questions, as most of them seem to have helpful answers that appear to address the question; your comments even suggest this is so. If they have an answer, please accept it).

If you really need to use a CTE here (meaning you're doing something recursive and aren't just using it for convenience instead of inline-selecting or inline-joining), the simplest and fastest workaround would probably be to include your SQL within your own call to `sp_executesql`. You'll end up nesting calls to it (which will look silly), but it shouldn't cause any actual problems.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the query up in an sp_executesql statement works great if you don't have parameters in the query, otherwise the parameters aren't parsed because they're in a quoted string by the time they get to ADO, and this results in a syntax error.

What I did to resolve this was to create a TADOQuery descendant, which overrides the constructor, as follows:

```
constructor TCPADOQuery.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  TWideStringList(SQL).OnChange := LocalQueryChanged;
end;
```

LocalQueryChanged then checks if the query starts with a common table expression, and inserts a dummy declaration at the beginning of the query, which the XP ADO parser does understand. A CTE must be preceded by a semicolon if it is not the first statement in the query, so we have to fix that first:

```
procedure TCPADOQuery.LocalQueryChanged(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: WideString;
begin
  if not (csLoading in ComponentState) then
    Close;
  a := Trim(SQL.Text);
  if Uppercase(copy(a, 1, 4)) = 'WITH' then a := ';' + a;
  if Uppercase(copy(a, 1, 5)) = ';WITH' then
    a := 'DECLARE @DummyForADO_XP BIT'#13#10 + a;
  CommandText := a;
end;
```

This has resolved the problem, and has saved me having to rework all of my code where I use both CTEs and parameters.

Comment: While I didn't use your full answer here, the trick of adding a dummy declaration at the beginning of the statement so that the XP parser works was a godsend.  Was supporting an Access front end to SQL Server and this was driving me nuts.